# How do I get variable unchanged in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Am trying to assign one variable value to another $scope variable (Or normal variable) in AngularJS script, and not modifying either of them after that. But I see both the variable values gets changed automatically - There is modification for some other variables after the above assignment.
Why is my variables ("d" and "$scope.dataset_d_final") which are not being modified gets changed automatically?
How can I prevent it?

I have below AngularJS code

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('ExampleApp', ['ui.plot']);
app.controller('PlotCtrl', function ($scope) 
 {
    'use strict';
    $scope.sname = "Tttt";
    $scope.dataset_v = {
     "d0": { "id": 0, "name": "Housing", "value": 18 }, 
     "d1": { "id": 1, "name": "Travel", "value": 31.08 },
     "d2": { "id": 2, "name": "Restaurant", "value": 64 },
     "d3": { "id": 3, "name": "Bank", "value": 3 },
     "d4": { "id": 4, "name": "Movies", "value": 10 }
                       };

    $scope.dataset_final={};

    $scope.assign = function () 
    {
        var dataset=$scope.dataset_v;
        // Declare resulting empty array

        var d = [];
        // Get object keys and iterate over them
          Object.keys(dataset).forEach(function (key)  
          {
            // Get the value from the object
            var value = dataset[key].value;
            // Update values if in the range
            if(value >= 10 && value <= 20) {
               dataset[key].value = 7;
            } else if(value > 20 && value <= 40) {
               dataset[key].value = 8;
            }
             d.push(dataset[key]);

            $scope.dataset_d_final = d;  // THIS IS THE ASSIGNMENT
         // "$scope.dataset_d_final" and "d" variables gets changed even after performing no modification later in the code


             //  REVERSING
            var dataset1 = $scope.dataset_v;
            var d1 = [];

            Object.keys(dataset1).forEach(function (key) {
                // Get the value from the object
                var value = dataset1[key].value;
                // Update values if in the range
                if (value == 2) {
                    dataset1[key].value = 1;
                } else if (value == 3) {
                    dataset1[key].value = 4;
                }
                d1.push(dataset1[key]);
            });
            alert('Final');
            alert(JSON.stringify($scope.dataset_d_final, null, 4));
            alert(JSON.stringify(d, null, 4));  // Both got changed as per above function

 });
</script>
```

My last alert for variables "d" and "$scope.dataset_d_final" should not be changed.. how can I do that ?

I want to post either of d or $scope.dataset_d_final data to the server via $http service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign one object value to another the both get same reference as object are reference type

like 
    var a = { prop1: 0, prop2: 0 }, b = {};// both are objects
    a = b ;
    changing in any of the object will make changes in both

```
a.prop1 = 1;
a.prop2 = 2;

console.log("Output: - ",b); // Output: - {prop1: 1, prop2: 2};
```

For avoiding such issue you could use `angular.copy` which will assign the value with different reference by cloning that object.

```
var dataset = angular.copy($scope.dataset_v); //assigning value with different reference.

//also while REVERSING
var dataset1 = angular.copy($scope.dataset_v);;
```

Comment: But am trying to get original value of $scope.dataset_d_final.. Why should I use angular.copy for $scope.dataset_v ? Could you please let me know ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't looked at your logic thoroughly, but you should use angular.copy while storing its old copy..

Comment: Not sure where to use angular.copy.. I tried while displaying as alert.. and I still see changed one